# Difference between sem_init and sema_init

Tags: linux, embedded, operating-system, semaphore, rtos

What is the difference between sema_init and sem_init ? Are there any specific usage scenarios and other dependencies for the respective APIs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- sema_init is from the Solaris *thread* library.
- sem_init is from the Posix *pthread* library.

See [Threads: Basic Theory and Libraries](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node29.html)

Answer (score 4):

Since you tagged this with "linux" I'll ignore other Unixes.

sema_init is the Linux kernel's counting semaphore implementation initialization function.
sem_init is the initializer from the Posix thread library (and is therefore used by userspace code).